# Salesforce Email Quick action not shown in Case Feed View

Tags: service-cloud-console, servicecloud, publisher-action

I want to add Email Quick Action in publisher view before Question(As displayed in below image). 
[image]

When i edit layout and trying to add Email Quick Action in Salesforce Classic Publisher, Email quick action is not available - (see below image)
[image]

Kindly Please Advice.

**Thanks

    Nirmallya Ghosh**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i found the Answer -

We need to change "Email Deliverability" Settings to "**All Emails**" instead of **System Emails** or **No Access**.

Comment: Phew, this saved a bit of head-banging-on-the-wall, if only this was documented properly here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=case_interaction_sending_email.htm&type=0

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable Email-to-Case in order to have this functionality. Please go to **Setup-->Case--> Email-to-Case** Enable Email-To-Case checkbox. 
Then go to the Case Page layout, you will find the option to add email quick action.

Comment: In Page Layout - Under Quick action Email is not available. In Screenshot 2.

Comment: Did you enable Email-To-Case? @NirmallyaGhosh

Comment: Email - to- Case is already enabled.